# Using external library in an Android Module (Library)

Tags: android

I'm working on an android library where I need to download image from online and cache them. So, I wanna use **picassa** to do this task.
But when I'm using any external library application got crashed and showing that

> Class Not fount exception

.

Here the Logcat file .

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.squareup.picasso.Picasso" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.application.thecodero.amarbill-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
```

and Error is showing here.

```
Picasso.with(Easypayway.this).load(imageUrl).into(mainLogo);
```

This error only showing only when I use the .arr file. But when I'm using the module (main lib file) it's not showing.

What's the problem here ?

Comment: Write this line in file build.gradle:

compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'

Comment: You mean , i have to write `compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'` also in my application gradle also !!

Comment: paste the build.gradle file content